# Navigation not working when the app is already running and Firebase Dynamic Links are used

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

I have this Loader Widget that checks for Dynamic Links and navigates to `/game` route(`gamePage()` widget) if the app was opened using a dynamic link. if the app was manually opened it will navigate to the `/home` route.

My code works fine for when the app is closed and then it is opened through a dynamic link.
But when the app is already open and is on the home page, then the code does not work because the context is empty.

Loader.dart

```
class Loader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoaderState createState() => _LoaderState();
}

class _LoaderState extends State<Loader> {


    Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
        final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
        final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
        print(deepLink);
        if (deepLink != null) {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/game');  //this works because app has just started
        }
        else{
          FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
              onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
                final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

                if (deepLink != null) {
                  print(context);     // prints null
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/game'); //this does not work because the app is already running and its on /home and context is null
                }
              },
              onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
                print('error Opening the link');
                print(e.message);
              }
          );
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');  // load home widget if there are no deep links
        }
      }

    @override
    void initState(){
      super.initState();
      initDynamicLinks();
    }


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       //Loading animation widget code
    }
}
```

main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: "/load",
    routes:<String, WidgetBuilder> {
      '/load': (context) => Loader(),
      '/home': (context) => Home(),
      '/game': (context) => gamePage(),
    },
  ),
  );
}
```

I am new to Flutter so any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. It doesn't work without context. So every time the deep link invokes you need to provide a context.

To implement that, create a custom class for the manage deep link. Then you can initiate that deep-link by providing context.

Please see the example below.

**Custome Class**

```
class DynamicLinkService {

  Future handleDynamicLinks(BuildContext context) async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data =
    await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

    _handleDeepLink(data, context);

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
          // handle link that has been retrieved
          _handleDeepLink(dynamicLink, context);
        }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('Link Failed: ${e.message}');
    });
  }

  void _handleDeepLink(PendingDynamicLinkData data, BuildContext context) {
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
    if (deepLink != null) {
      print('_handleDeepLink | deeplink: $deepLink');

      var isPost = deepLink.pathSegments.contains('post');
      var isInvite = deepLink.pathSegments.contains('invite');
      if(isInvite){
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
            NavigationHomeScreen()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Initiate the deep-link from your Loader widget**

```
class Loader extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoaderState createState() => _LoaderState();
}

class _LoaderState extends State<Loader> {

  final DynamicLinkService _dynamicLinkService = DynamicLinkService();

    @override
    void initState(){
      super.initState();
      _dynamicLinkService.handleDynamicLinks(context);
    }


    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       //Loading animation widget code
    }
}
```